# How to read and change the system measurement units in control panel regional and Language advanced settings

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE, I have written an application that runs alongside another App written by my Client in Japan, The problem is that the Japanese software (measuring machine) is not the best user interface design, and the machine Regional advanced Measurement settings have to be changed before starting the app to select Metric or Imperial units of measurement.

I was wondering if i could help the users by flipping this system setting for them and launching the Japanese app from my App, I have no problem starting the Japanese App, just how to read and change the measurement setting.

I have used

```
`  shortdateformat     := 'dd/mm/yy';

`  longdateformat      := 'dd/mm/yyyy';

`  dateseparator       := '/';`
Application.UpdateFormatSettings := False;
```

Application.UpdateMetricSettings := false;

Many times in my applications to play with the local system snapshots when my app starts but now i NEED to change the actual live system values. I have been up and down the delphi help and Microsoft MSDN library documentation but just cant find anything relating to measurement units and how to access them.

How can i do this in Delphi XE. ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `SetLocaleInfo` with LOCALE_IMEASURE, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, LOCALE_SLONGDATE etc..?

Comment: Brilliant..anychance you could possible show me the construct for setting LOCALE_IMEASURE to Metric ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GetLocaleInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`SetLocaleInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get/set measurement system or other locale related setting. Example to change to metric system:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LocaleID: LCID;
begin
  LocaleID := GetUserDefaultLCID;
  SetLocaleInfo(LocaleID, LOCALE_IMEASURE, '0'); // '1' for US system
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
end;
```

For further information on specific settings see "[Locale Information Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Comment: Thanks so much i will try this tomorrow, its 23:20...Im off home.